# Why is my Django app loading CSS from another app no matter what I change in any file?

Tags: html, css, django

This is quite a unique problem and I may be doing something completely dumb.

I am designing a web app for job information, payroll, expenses, etc. for a mechanical contractor as my first large project. I have designed a calculator and a to-do list with login in the past and never had this problem.

I have created two apps so far in this project: login and tickets. login takes care of the homepage and login while tickets make a list of all service reports with details, displays them, and will soon be able to order/search them once I get this stupid problem fixed.

No matter what I change in my tickets app's base.html, the ticket app's css/static is inheriting from the login app's css as shown by get requests. hard refresh does nothing but keep showing "static/login/style.css." I feel my tickets templates are inheriting from the login app's base.html, but I don't know why...

STATICFILES_DIRS won't seem to help me here and my STATIC_URL is the default 'static/.' I feel like that could be the problem but I don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Lucas

Comment: can you share image of folder structure and static file folder for better understanding